# Domain not linking to files?

Tags: domains, error

I've purchased a domain ( educateapp.co.uk ) and hosting for it. I've hosted the files in the /public_html/ folder, and have a index.html file. However nothing shows up when I visit the domain. It's handled with CPanel. It's set as a website, and active in settings. Am I missing something or does it take a lot of time to work? Only got the domain 12 hours ago.

Comment: Complete DNS Resolution may take upto 48 Hours.

Comment: It could be a DNS issue.    You could be logged into the wrong cPanel account.   You could have messed something up in cPanel.   Your host may have broken something.   It isn't possible to diagnose the problem from the information that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment above, it may take upto 48 hrs for DNS propagation.

However, in the meanwhile you may access your site [by altering your hosts file.](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/)

It basically maps your domain name to your ip address on just your computer so you can play around before DNS propagation is complete. Remember to undo the change after 48 hrs.

Comment: Ah ok. I assumed that because it changed from BT Address help to the current 404 that propagation had ended. I'm running the website locally for testing etc, I used htaccess if I remember correctly. So just wait it out? It's UK hosting so 24 hours instead?